# How many spaces to a tab on this tty

Tags: perl, spacing, tty, terminfo

I have a perl script that is writing to stdout which is a tty.  Is there a way to determine how many spaces to a tab on that tty?

Comment: Generally the "standard" is 8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the 'it' capability from [terminfo](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-Terminfo/).

```
use Term::Terminfo;
my $ti = Term::Terminfo->new; 
$tabsize = $ti->getnum( "it" );
```

Comment: What does the "it"-argument mean?

Comment: @sid_com - init_tabs. Google's your friend. One of the first 3 links on googling "terminfo it tab" yields: "it# - Initial number of spaces between tabs."; http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hltermcommands.html